# Javascript Regex Look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

In my web app I need to remove all whitespace and line breaks before and after the content between a pair of ``` `` ```. Example:

``` ``\s\s\s\s\stest1234\s\s\s\s23432\s\s\s\s\s\s\s`` ``` would become something like this: ``` ``test1234\s\s\s\s23432`` ```.

(`\s` is a whitespace)

The regex I wrote for this is: ``` /(``(?<=[\s]*)[^`]*(?=[\s]*)``)/g ``` but I found out JS doesn't have look behind, how would I transform this regex into something that does the job?

My JavaScript would look something like this:

```
replace(/(``(?<=[\s]*)[^`]*(?=[\s]*)``)/g, function(match, p1) {
    return p1;
})
```

Note, I only want to remove the outer whitespace, the ones that belong to the content need t be preserved.

Comment: \s contains \t and \n so you can remove them for clearer regex
/``[\s]*([^`]*)[\s]*``/g

Answer (score 1):

Make it two steps.

```
var src = "``     test123423432    \n\n   ``";
var results = src.replace(/``([\s\S]*?)``/g,function(_,m) {
    // note [\s\S] above is to handle JS's lack of a DOTALL flag
    return "``"+m.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")+"``"; // trim all whitespace
});
```

If a problem seems too hard, usually breaking it down into smaller problems is the answer.

Comment: Does this also handle spaces inside of the string?

Comment: This handles all spaces that are contained in the double-backtick delimiters. Try it and see if it's what you need.

Comment: I see your edit, @MartijnRiemers - Answer updated to only *trim* spaces, not *delete*.

Comment: You missed a `+` for the trailing spaces. Otherwise, this solution is something that is clean and easy to understand.